# Application crashes trying to retrieve view contents from ListView using SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, crash, simpleadapter

I am having an issue with trying to retrieve the contents of the view that the the user has clicked within a ListView. My ListView is setup using a SimpleAdapter and is comprised of a "heading" and a "sub-title" for each of the items in the list. These are stored using a HashMap.

Within the activity also, is a spinner, when the user selects an item in the spinner, the ListView is updated. This is working fine and I just thought it necessary to mention what is happening within the activity as well.

What I am trying to do, is retrieve which item the user has selected so I can guide them to a new activity based on their selection (right now just trying to display the view contents with Toast). I want to retrieve the contents of what is stored under the "engExp" key for the item.

Here is my code:

```
    // HASHMAP FOR LISTVIEW
    List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for(int x = 0; x < expressionListForModule.getCount(); x++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("engExp", expressionListForModule.getString(0));
        map.put("japDef", expressionListForModule.getString(1));
        fillMaps.add(map);
        expressionListForModule.moveToNext();
    }

    // SETUP LISTVIEW
    SimpleAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"engExp","japDef"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.expressionList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter2);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Specifically, the item that is causing the application to crash is this:
((TextView) view).getText()

If you need to see any more of my code, please let me know.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to write the code to get the text from the TextView is within the onItemclick()) method and also by using view argument u can get that text...Try this  String contentForLink=view.getText().toString();

Comment: This thorws an error as follows:
The method getText() is undefined for the type View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        String contentForLink = v.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contentForLink, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: That stops the crashing for sure! However, something odd is happening now. Instead of displaying the content from the list item itself, the text of the Spinner item itself is what shows up. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't working with the code you put in the first time around. But after typing it in again, it worked perfectly! Must have been a silly error on my part somewhere. Thanks so much.